# how to get props from functional component inside class component in React Native

Tags: react-native

Currently I have a class component that contains functional component that show date picker from function component
but i want to get selected values in parent class component
My Code is that
Class component

```
export default class TransactionHistory extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      }
      state = {
         Participant :'' ,
         DateFrom :'' }
 render() {

        return (
<View style={styles.PageContainer}>
               <Test  />
</View>
)}
}
```

functional Component

```
 export default function date() {
      const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
      const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
     
      const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
        alert(selectedDate)
      };
    const showMode = currentMode => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
      };
       const showDatepicker = () => {
        showMode('date');
      };
      const showTimepicker = () => {
        showMode('time');
      };
      return (
        <View>
          <View>
            <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Button onPress={showTimepicker} title="Show time picker!" />
          </View>
           {show && (  
            <DateTimePicker
              testID="dateTimePicker"
               value={date}
               mode={mode}
                 is24Hour={true}
               display="default"
               onChange={onChange}
            
                      
            />
            )}   
        </View>
      );
    };
```

please help me

Comment: Let create handle onChange function on the class component and send it to functional component via props. In onChange function of the functional component, call the parent's onChange with selected value.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TransactionHistory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
    Participant: '',
    DateFrom: '',
    TestValue: '',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.PageContainer}>
        <Text>{this.state.TestValue} </Text>
        <Test
          callback={(someValue) =>
            this.setState({ ...this.state, TestValue: someValue })
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Test: React.FC = ({ callback }) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
      callback(someValue);
  };

  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };
  const showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode('date');
  };
  const showTimepicker = () => {
    showMode('time');
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button onPress={showTimepicker} title="Show time picker!" />
      </View>
      {show && (
        <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={date}
          mode={mode}
          is24Hour={true}
          display="default"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```